# How does one pass the properties of a $_POST to a Function?

Tags: php, forms

I would like to pass the properties to a function to Update details in a database. I want all the columns that were selected in the form to be passed to a function. Frankly, I don't know what to do.

My code is the following:

```
if (isset($_POST["updateWineButton"])) {

    $wineID = $_POST["wineID"];
    $wineCountryID = $_POST["wineCountryID"];
    $wineSizeID = $_POST["wineSizeID"];
    $wineRatingID = $_POST["wineRatingID"];
    $wineColourID = $_POST["wineColourID"];
    $packageID = $_POST["packageID"];
    $wineCategoryID = $_POST["wineCategoryID"];
    $wineCode = $_POST["wineCode"];
    $price = $_POST["price"];
    $description = $_POST["description"];
    $wineRating = $_POST["wineRating"];
    $wineIMG = $_POST["wineIMG"];

    updateWine($updateWine);
    $status = "$description has been updated.";
}
```

Update Wine Function

```
function updateWine($wineUpdate)
{
    global $pdo;
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE WINE SET wineID=?, wineCountryID=?, wineSizeID=?, wineRatingID, wineColourID=?,
                            packageID=?, wineCategoryID=?, wineCode=?, price=?, description=?, wineRating=?, wineIMG=?
                            WHERE wineID=?");

    $statement->execute([$wineUpdate->wineID,
        $wineUpdate->wineCountryID,
        $wineUpdate->wineSizeID,
        $wineUpdate->wineRatingID,
        $wineUpdate->wineColourID,
        $wineUpdate->packageID,
        $wineUpdate->wineCategoryID,
        $wineUpdate->wineCode,
        $wineUpdate->price,
        $wineUpdate->description,
        $wineUpdate->wineRatingID,
        $wineUpdate->wineIMG]);

    $statement->fetch();
}
```

Comment: `$updateWine` isn't defined. Can you show your `updateWine()` function?

Comment: @RossWilson yes that is my issue. I would like to pass the $_POST to the updateWine function but that's not allowed. I have updated the post.

Comment: Are you worried about validation i.e. what if a user doesn't fill one of the form values in?

Comment: @RossWilson yes I am worried about validation. I would just like for the database to be updated on form submission first. I tried the answer below but its not updating. Also says $description is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly you want to do something like this,

```
if (isset($_POST["updateWineButton"])) {
  $result = updateWine($_POST);
  if($result){
    $status = "$description has been updated.";
  }else{
    $status = "An error occurred.";
  }
}

//your function woud then look like ...

function updateWine($postdata){
  $wineID = $postdata["wineID"];
  $wineCountryID = $postdata["wineCountryID"];
  $wineSizeID = $postdata["wineSizeID"];
  $wineRatingID = $postdata["wineRatingID"];
  $wineColourID = $postdata["wineColourID"];
  $packageID = $postdata["packageID"];
  $wineCategoryID = $postdata["wineCategoryID"];
  $wineCode = $postdata["wineCode"];
  $price = $postdata["price"];
  $description = $postdata["description"];
  $wineRating = $postdata["wineRating"];
  $wineIMG = $postdata["wineIMG"];
  //udpate your database with the above values
  //check if update is successful
  return true;
  //else if there was an error
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I've tried this but it's not working

Comment: that's because I have only given you a general form of a function since it wasn't clear for your question that you actually wanted to know how to save your values to the DB.  I guest [Ross Wilson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1033654/ross-wilson) answered your question.

Comment: If [Ross Wilson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1033654/ross-wilson)'s answer is what you wanted please select his reply as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following should work for you:

```
function updateWine()
{
    global $pdo;

    $keys = [
        "wineID", "wineCountryID", "wineSizeID", "wineRatingID", "wineColourID", "packageID", "wineCategoryID",
        "wineCode", "price", "description", "wineRating", "wineIMG",
    ];

    $results = [];

    foreach ($keys as $index) {
        if (isset($_POST[$index])) {
            $results[$index] = $_POST[$index];
        }
    }

    $statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE WINE SET " . implode('=?, ', array_keys($results)) . "=? WHERE wineID =?");

    $statement->execute(array_merge(array_values($results), [$_POST['wineID']]));

    $statement->fetch();
}

if (isset($_POST["updateWineButton"]) && isset($_POST['wineID'])) {
    updateWine();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I've changed my code to the above and now I am getting undfefined indexes for each of the wine columns and a warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens.

Comment: My bad, I'd written `$_GET` instead of `$_POST` in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: I've updated it now. I'm not getting any errors except for undefined variable description but it's not updating the database.

Comment: I would imagine that's because you still have `$status = "$description has been updated.";` but the description variable isn't getting defined anymore. You can just recreate it like you had in your original example but I would suggest putting some sort of check in to it to make sure that it was included in the request.

Comment: @Kay you should select this answer as the correct one and give Ross the benefit for the effort in answering your question, this is important to continue to encourage people to answer your questions on this forum.